# How to get a list with all the possible combinations of the elements inside another list?

Tags: list, prolog

I have a list that has as elements: atoms and other lists. I ask the following:

> -? totobola([1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,[1,x],[1,x,2]],LS).

I want the `LS` to be a list where I would show every atom followed by the possible combinations of the lists inside the given list.

> LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,1,1];
>   LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,1,x];
>   LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,1,2];
>   LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,x,1];
>   LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,x,x];
>   LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,x,2];
>   no

My current solution:

```
lista([_|_]):- true, !.
lista(_):- false.

totobola([],[]).
totobola([X|T1],[Y|T2]):-
    lista(X),
    !,
    member(Y,X),
    totobola(T1,T2).
totobola([X|T1],[X|T2]):-
    totobola(T1,T2).
```

With `lista` I check if `X` is a list or not but instead of getting `LS=[1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,2,1,x,1,1];` I get `LS = [1, x, 2, 1, x, 2, 1, x, 2|...]`

Can someone guide me or at least tell me what I'm doing wrong or less right?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Make sure you're looking at the [whole list](http://www.swi-prolog.org/FAQ/AllOutput.html). And, technically, you should have `lista([]).` and `lista([_|_]).` (rather than `lista([_|_]) :- true, !`) but I don't think it impacts your current solution. You can omit `lista(_) :- false.` because anything that isn't declared as true via rule or fact will fail by default.

Comment: Please provide more (and smaller) examples! Also, explain what the atoms and lists stand for...

Comment: @lurker you're right about `lista` I can and will omit the false clause. I'll make sure I'm looking at the whole list and get back to you.

@repeat For example: `[1,x,2,1,x, [x,1],[1,x,2]]` in this case by atoms I'm referring to the single elements in the list: `1,x,2,1,x` and by list everything that is inside these brackets `[x,1]` and `[1,x,2]`.

Comment: Please explain what `1`, `2`, `x`, `[1,x,2]`, `[x,1]` *mean*. What does `1` stand for (that `2` does not)? What does `[x,1]` stand for? Same for `[1,x]`, `[1,x,x]`, `[x,x]`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a 'repeat.' query then press 'w' key and '.' you will enter write mode and see all the values within the list.

?- repeat.
true [write] --> after pressing w once
true . --> enter a dot to exit

Answer (score 0):

We had this exercise in ALGAV class,ISEP (Portugal) , and the solution was:

```
is_list(X) :- var(X), !, fail.
is_list([]).
is_list([_|T]) :- is_list(T).

totobola([],[]).
totobola([H|T],[X|LR]):- is_list(H), !, member(X,H), totobola(T,LR). 
totobola([H|T],[H|LR]):- totobola(T,LR).
```